# Как поймать цикл на значении, равном текущему значению из GET (for)?

Tags: php, html, циклы

Пытаюсь организовать красивый и информативный нумератор страниц. 
Есть следующий код:

```
<div id="pager"><?php
        if (isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $color="style='background-color:#66E95D;'";
            $pn=($_GET['page']);
            for($i=1,$j=1; $i<=$pkol; $j++,$i=$j)
            {?>
                                       <!-- Вот здесь необходимо что-то делать... -->
                <a href='?view=kotel&page=<?php echo $i;?>'
                <?php if ($pn=$i) {echo $color;}?> ><?php echo $i;?></a>&nbsp;
                                       <!-- Вот здесь необходимо что-то делать... -->
            <?php }
        }
        else
        {
            for($i=1,$j=1; $i<=$pkol; $j++,$i=$j)
                  {echo "<a href='?view=kotel&page=$i'>$i</a>&nbsp;";}
        }?>
            <span>Страницы</span>
        </div>
```

Задача в следующем: необходимо подсвечивать текущий номер страницы.

**Вопрос:** как соорудить условие в цикле for таким образом, чтобы подсвечивался только тот номер, который соответствует значению из GET.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($pn=$i)
```

Возможно, ошибка кроется здесь?

И да, зачем городить:

`for($i=1,$j=1; $i<=$pkol; $j++,$i=$j);`

Когда можно:

`for ($i = 1; $i <= $pkol; $i++);`

Comment: это не то, чтобы ошибка... осталось после прежних манипуляций. 
А за правку условия отдельное спасибо!

Comment: аааааааааа =))))))
поначалу не обратил внимания. Невнимательность, чтоб ее...

$pn==$i

Answer (score 0):

я бы вот как зделал:

получаем номер тек страници. Далее имеем общее кол-во страниц. Делим Общее колво на отрезок Перваястран....(ТекСтран-1)|ТекСтран|(ТекСтран+1)......ПослСтран

а там уже 2цикла но без условия и между ними вывод активной страницы, то есть мы знаем что С Перваястран....(ТекСтран-1) и (ТекСтран+1)......ПослСтран - нинада ничего проверять

Comment: Да, идея хороша. Но в моем случае не актуальна: страниц не будет более 3 - 4. Поэтому не вижу смысла.

Comment: ну если мало страниц то да